# ABBYY OCR - How to use multiple region parameters in the Uri?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri, ocr, abbyy

I'm working with ABBYY cloud OCR, when my popruse is to scan 3 specific places in each document that I'm scanning. These 3 places will always be the same so I want to use the `ProcessFields` function do it and having some problems with it.
When I want to scan only one specific place I used this :

```
string url1 = String.Format("http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processFields?region=0,0,200,200&language=english");
```

When trying to scan 2 places I've tried this :

```
    string url1 = String.Format("http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processFields?region=0,0,200,200 region 100,100,100,100&language=english");
```

it gave me an error.
Anyone has any advise how to do it?
I also tried defieng 3 Uri's but as the upload is done only once - how can I reach the 2 other Uri's without scanning it again?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I've not heard of Abbyy. Do they have support available for their SDK/API?

Comment: They hold small documentation, that I just can't understand

Comment: Hey Ilya.. not sure I understood you, are you talking about ABBYY? or another OCR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation of processField method](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processFields/), you can't pass field parameters in URI, you should form an [XML](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/specifications/xml-scheme-field-settings/) and submit it using POST method instead of GET. There is also a sample XML file on that page.

Simple method with URI works only for one field and [processTextField](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processTextField/) method.